# how to run a script on auditd events?

Tags: linux-audit, events

I have configured auditd to track some sensitive files on my system. Now I would to have a script that will be called each time auditd writes a line, with the `$1` argument of that script being the line added.

From what I read in the manual auditd has no such option.

Is there a way to do this anyway?

If I'll have a cron script running every minute, I will have a problem defining it on which lines it should work (which lines are new? if any?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the tail command like so:

```
tail -Fn0 /var/log/audit/audit.log | /sbin/script
```

and `/sbin/script` is like so:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  #something to do with $line variable when it comes
done
```

Comment: you may wish to tail `-F` instead of `-f` so that this still works when the log file is rotated.