# Running a script when a particular command is run

Tags: shell-script, scripting, security, kali-linux, alias

I want to run "./dothis.sh" if someone executes "cat abc.txt"

Is there some way to do this without using alias?

I want to use this for strengthening security of some specific files on a server.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

```
man auditd
man auditd.conf
```

Is what you're looking for and then you run a command once there's a line being logged:

1. [How to log all commands run on Linux including their arguments (parameters)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/765179/how-to-log-all-commands-run-on-linux-including-their-arguments-parameters)
2. [How to run a script on auditd events?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350081/how-to-run-a-script-on-auditd-events)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what i want is:
I have a passwords file (encrypted of course) which is accessible to the root user.
I want to prepare for a "break-in", per say, where the root user is compromised. So, if someone, using the root user tries to view that file with vim or cat, i want them to be locked in an infinite loop, so that they have to exit the terminal on their end. I dont want the keyboard interuption to work. But, if i use the whole path of the utility
Eg."/usr/bin/cat"
Then it should work.
Basically... I want to create an alias where "cat " runs a custom script.
I require the script as well as how to properly alias it.
Thanks