# Is there any way to change file owner when some user modify the file?

Tags: ubuntu, users, chown

For example, user1 create file. That file's owner is user1. if user2 modify that file's contents and save it. After that, file's owner changed to user2. is it possible? if possible how can do that?

(ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way...

my thought would be to use the existing Linux audit subsystem, which in modern linux is pretty good now compared to kernel 2.6 days and earlier, having the `/etc/audit/audit.rules` file customized.

You would use the **watch** feature to *watch* specified files and folders for being edited.  Then that would show up as an entry in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and could be easily found based on an *audit filter key* as specified by the `-k` option of the audit watch rule, and you would have the specific time it happened and by who.

Up to this point would be a reliable way of knowing.  The trick now would be queuing off `audit.log` for whenever the entry happens and then performing a `chown` on said file/folder, which my first thought would be to write your own C program, that would run as root most likely, to be able to first read `audit.log` and then perform the `chown` command.  And then how often and how immediate do you need this to happen after a given file/folder edit... a cron job to run such a C program as root to read `audit.log` every 1, 5, or 15 minutes?  I do not know off hand if there is a way to cause linux audit to *exec* some command based on whenever an event is captured (which would seem to be the ideal way).

quick reference about audit.rules: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html

a hardcore example of `/etc/audit/audit.d/rules` in rhel 7 :

```
## First rule - delete all
-D

## Increase the buffers to survive stress events.
## Make this bigger for busy systems
# -b 8192

# set from 8k to 1mb
-b 1048576


# 2 is shutdown, 1 is runlevel 1
#

-f 2


-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve -C uid!=euid -F euid=0 -k setuid
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -C uid!=euid -F euid=0 -k setuid
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve -C gid!=egid -F egid=0 -k setgid
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -C gid!=egid -F egid=0 -k setgid

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S chown -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chown -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S chmod -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chmod -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod


-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S setxattr -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S setxattr -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S open -F exit=-EPERM -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k access
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S open -F exit=-EACCES -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k access
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S open -F exit=-EPERM -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k access
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S open -F exit=-EACCES -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k access

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/semanage -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/setsebool -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chcon -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/setfiles -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change

-w /var/run/faillock -p wa -k logins
-w /var/log/lastlog -p wa -k logins

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/passwd -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/unix_chkpwd -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/gpasswd -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chage -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/userhelper -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/su -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change 
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/sudo -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change 

-w /etc/sudoers -p wa -k privileged-actions
-w /etc/sudoers.d/ -p wa -k privileged-actions

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/newgrp -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chsh -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S mount -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-mount
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S mount -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-mount
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/mount -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-mount

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/umount -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-mount
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/postdrop -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-postfix
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/postqueue -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-postfix
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-keysign -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-ssh
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/crontab -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-cron
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/pam_timestamp_check -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-pam
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S create_module -k module-change
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S create_module -k module-change
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S init_module -k module-change
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S init_module -k module-change


-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S delete_module -k module-change
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S delete_module -k module-change

-w /usr/bin/kmod -p x -F auid!=unset -k module-change
-w /etc/passwd -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/group -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/gshadow -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/shadow -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/security/opasswd -p wa -k identity

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S unlink -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k delete
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S unlink -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k delete

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S unlink,unlinkat,rename,renameat,rmdir -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k delete
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S unlink,unlinkat,rename,renameat,rmdir -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k delete

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S init_module,finit_module -k modulechange
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S init_module,finit_module -k modulechange

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S creat,open,openat,open_by_handle_at,truncate,ftruncate -F exit=-EPERM -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k access
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S creat,open,openat,open_by_handle_at,truncate,ftruncate -F exit=-EACCES -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k access
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S creat,open,openat,open_by_handle_at,truncate,ftruncate -F exit=-EPERM -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k access
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S creat,open,openat,open_by_handle_at,truncate,ftruncate -F exit=-EACCES -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k access

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S setxattr,fsetxattr,lsetxattr,removexattr,fremovexattr,lremovexattr -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S setxattr,fsetxattr,lsetxattr,removexattr,fremovexattr,lremovexattr -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S chmod,fchmod,fchmodat -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chmod,fchmod,fchmodat -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S chown,fchown,fchownat,lchown -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chown,fchown,fchownat,lchown -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
```

Comment: Nice! I believe that the audit subsystem pretty much uses similar techniques to what I propose under the hood, but probably more elegantly using probes.

Comment: fyi : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350081/how-to-run-a-script-on-auditd-events

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically it's possible: use `fanotify` to watch the files or directories you're interested in, handle the observed events, read each write event's pid field, figure out the user behind that PID, change ownership of the file. However, this requires you to write your own program, probably in C. It has severe effects on performance of writing to files, as well.

It also feels like at odds with typical usage of files on Unixoid systems. I'd recommend finding a different way to achieve whatever you set out to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set certain owners to a file, regardless of who creates or modifies a file you might want to explore the "sticky bits" (also "setuid"- and "setgid"-bits) of directories.

Otherwise you could include the change of ownership into the call for your means of editing the file, similar to what "sudoedit" does. This method isn't fool- or bullet-prove, but simple to accomplish:

Let us assume your users will use some "edit" to edit the files in question. You move the "edit"-binary to another another name (say: "edit-bin") and then create a script "edit" like this:

```
#! /bin/sh

local chUser=$(get_user)
local fTmp="${1}.$$"

/path/to/edit-bin "$1"
if ! diff "$1" "$fTmp" ; then
     mv "$fTmp" "${1}"
     chown "${chUser} ${1}
fi

exit 0
```

This script is just meant as a barebone example, it is easy to implement keeping a backup copy and other seucrity measures i left out here. In a production script i would also make the exit code meaningful. Also notice that you need the script to run under root, which means you either need "edit-bin" to be secure against a shell-escape (no i.e. "vi", therefore) or you need to run "edit-bin" under the real UID, not root.

Comment: A normal user cannot change the ownership of a file. Either you need to use the root account or have CAP_CHOWN assigned to your account. Setting `setuid` on a directory is a no-op.

Comment: @doneal24: You are right - this is why i said "similar to what sudoedit does" - you need to run the script under root but you want the edit part either free of a shell escape or run under the real user. Why you can't set sticky bits on a directory eludes me.

Comment: You can use setgid on a directory and all new files will be group-owned by that group assuming that the creator account is also a member of the group. This is however easily evaded, for instance by creating a file by extracting it from a tar archive. One reason setuid does not work is because it would be an excellent way to avoid disk quotas. You can also use it to create a file that you then cannot access, e.g. file permissions are 0600  and you give away the file. Finally, the sticky bit is used on Linux system. `/tmp` is perm 01777. You can create files but you cannot delete other's files.